# Dont want to display end date for paypal adaptive payments

Tags: php, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments

I got this paypal adaptive payment to work on live. Now my question is when we get redirect to paypal screen for pre-approval request how do I hide the end date of the pre-approval because it makes the users confuse(Enddatum in the left column).

If this is not possible can write a short note about this on the paypal screen?

[image]

Thanks in advance.